# How do I perform a git remote add from Sublime Text editor

Tags: sublimetext2

I perform any other git related command from ctrl-shift-p , except it appears I need to switch to the bash shell to add a remote repo - is this possible within ST2?

Thanks!

Comment: Guessing you are using one of the git plugins available for Sublime Text. You will need to check the plugin page to see what is available. If it's not, you can make a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the Git plugin, in the command palette you can go to "Git: Custom command" and type:

```
remote add <name> <url>
```